# How to submit feature enhancements from SE to Wolfram?

Tags: discussion

It is sometimes the case that questions on Mathematica SE lead to requests for enhancement.  So, I was wondering how best to get these enhancement requests into the hands of Wolfram developers?

I have a site license support contract with Wolfram and so I could, in theory, email them to say 'See that on SE?...I want that too please' but I'm unlikely to go to that level of trouble unless I feel that I REALLY want it

Would it be possible, or indeed desirable, to have a 'Submit this question as an enhancement request to Wolfram' button that would be available to users with very high rep?

Comment: There was a similar question asked here before, titled something like "A wish list for Mathematica". I personally was thinking that having some missing features listed as separate answers with their vote count could have been useful, having in mind also targets for the open source development undertaken by the community, not just the info for WRI. For better or for worse, a number of other high-rep users disagreed, so the question was closed and apparently deleted, since I can not find it now.

Comment: That question is [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/670/5) (10k users only; the deletion was automatic). There's a big difference between these two questions. The first was an equivalent of "If you had a genie what would you ask it" question, which wasn't really going to get anywhere meaningful. This question on the other hand, is a feature-request to implement a button for high rep users that sends a bat signal to WRI. Unfortunately, I can tell right now from past experience that this will be rejected by SE, but it certainly is a more focused question than the other one. @Leon

Comment: @rm-rf Ok, thanks for the ref. Leaving out the unconstructive debate about the usefulness of that question, why don't you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 4):

While I understand the motivation behind this request, the chances of this happening at present are next to none, because

- There is no convenient API to submit suggestions to WRI (the best that can be done is popping up an email template as in the new predictive interface)
- There would probably need to be some formal agreement/collaboration between WRI and SE, and none exists at the moment.

Besides, what's cool for us is not really what's cool for WRI... they're guided by their core principles, strategic objectives, technical constraints, corporate growth, etc. and not necessarily community opinion (heyooo multiple undo!). A good number of the developers already hang out here regularly, so at some level, they're familiar with what the community wants/needs/links.

Nevertheless, it's probably not a bad idea to send them feedback and suggestions — in the stray hope that someone considers them seriously — and that is best done via email or from the [contact page](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/).